# Query protractor to get value from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, protractor

I am using protractor for angular 2, i am able to get a value in the ui using protractor. Now i want to compare the value that i got from UI against mongodb.

for example: i got the value of "Toyota" in the UI (front end) angular 2 using protractor.
Now there is a collection in mongodb, collection name: cars. how to compare both.

1. UI = console.log(text) = the text has the value of "Toyota"
2. Mongodb = db.cars.find({""}) = this gives value as "Toyota".

I tried the below, but its not working.

```
expect(text).toEqual('db.cars.find({""})');
```

How to compare both (1 and 2) using protractor?

Any comments/answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your browser, which is the environment protractor runs in does not connect directly to the database. There will be an API layer in between, or are you actually using something like [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)? What you are asking is far too broad anyway.

Comment: forgot to say that nodejs is used